# Codility NailingPlanks - Using Binary Search on Nail Count Instead of Planks

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

**I have already read through the answers on this question - [Codility NailingPlanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133735/codility-nailingplanks).
This is not a duplicate, as I'm trying to solve this problem using a different approach - instead of running a binary search on the planks that a given nail can cover, I'm trying to run it on the total number of nails required to cover all the planks.**

This is my code:

```
def solution(A, B, C):
    min_nails = 1
    max_nails = len(C)
    valid = []
    while (min_nails <= max_nails):
        mid_nails = (min_nails + max_nails) // 2
        if (is_valid_nails_amount(mid_nails,A,B,C)):
            max_nails = mid_nails - 1
            valid.append(mid_nails)
        else: 
            min_nails = mid_nails + 1
    return -1 if len(valid) == 0 else min(valid)

def is_valid_nails_amount(nails,A,B,C): 
    candidates=C[0:nails]
    min_cover = min(candidates)
    max_cover = max(candidates)
    isValid = True
    for (a,b) in zip(A,B): 
        if not(min_cover in range(a, b + 1) or max_cover in range(a, b + 1) or a in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1) or b in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1)): 
            isValid = False
            break 
    return isValid
```

The algorithm begins by checking the first `len(C) + 1 / 2` nails in C:

1. First it calculates the smallest and largest value that the nails in this range can cover (`min_cover` and `max_cover`).
2. Next, it looks through A & B, and checks whether each plank can be nailed by any of the nails in the range `(min_cover, max_cover)`.
3. If the result is `False`, we update `min_nails` to be `mid_nails + 1` and repeat. If the result is `True`, we store the number of nails in the `valid` array, and attempt to find a smaller amount of nails which would also work, by setting `max_nails = mid_nails - 1`

This approach scores 100% correctness, however fails on the performance tests because it produces incorrect results - for each of the performance tests, the minimum number of nails [obtained](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training27RW3J-8TK/) is much lower than the expected result. I suspect the error would be in this line: `if not(min_cover in range(a, b + 1) or max_cover in range(a, b + 1) or a in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1) or b in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1))`

but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: [mincover,maxcover] overlapping [a,b] does *not* imply that there's a nail that actually hits the plank.   What if the highest and lowest nails are numbers 0 and 1?  You'd never return more than 2.

Comment: There are also a other problems.  Are you sure that `in range(...)` doesn't iterate?  The binary search isn't quite right.  You shouldn't copy the nails list to make 'candidates'

Comment: if the lowest nail is 0 and the highest nail is 1, wouldn't that imply it should cover all the planks in the range [0,1]?

Comment: Nails at positions 1 and 4 don't nail plank [2,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `if` condition can be seen with this sample input:

```
A = [1,3,5]
B = [2,4,6]
C = [1,5,3]
print(solution(A, B, C))
```

This will print 2, but the expected output is 3, as all three nails are needed.

Yet, your code will have `is_valid_nails_amount(2, A, B, C)` return `True`, despite the fact that the second plank is not nailed by those two nails.

The problem is that neither of these conditions guarantees that a nail hits the plank `(a, b)`:

```
a in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1)
b in range(min_cover, max_cover + 1)
```

Your algorithm really needs to check if there is a nail in that min/max range that is available for hitting the plank.